# Pipenv: "There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies." when trying to use version range

Tags: python, pipenv

I'm using `pipenv` to manage my virtual environment for some Python code that has to run as part of a build. I'm attempting to test out some pre-release code. My pre-release Python versioning looks like: `1.1.2-pr-232-21.`

If I specify a specific version (`deploymentlib = "==1.1.2-pr-232-21"`), pipenv runs successfully and creates the environment. However if I say something like `deploymentlib = "~=1.1", I get

```
$ pipenv install
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...

Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
Could not find a version that matches deploymentlib<1.0 (from -r /var/folders/hv/ftbzghbx7q30_1kzz_jg08dm3dv9gx/T/pipenv-8gm1zfoy-requirements/pipenv-kuxz3gwa-constraints.txt (line 2))
Tried: 1.1.2-pr-232-15, 1.1.2-pr-232-15, 1.1.2-pr-232-16, 1.1.2-pr-232-16, 1.1.2-pr-232-17, 1.1.2-pr-232-17, 1.1.2-pr-232-18, 1.1.2-pr-232-18, 1.1.2-pr-232-19, 1.1.2-pr-232-19, 1.1.2-pr-232-20, 1.1.2-pr-232-20, 1.1.2-pr-232-21, 1.1.2-pr-232-21, 1.1.2-pr-232-22, 1.1.2-pr-232-22, 1.1.2-pr-232-23, 1.1.2-pr-232-23, 1.1.2-pr-232-24, 1.1.2-pr-232-24, 1.0.0, 1.0.5, 1.0.5, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.6, 1.1.0, 1.1.0
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies.
```

I am not storing the lockfile in version control. Using the latest `pipenv` and Python 3.7.0.

Comment: Where does the req constraint `deploymentlib<1.0` come in?  `deploymentlib~=1.1` will not satisfy that constraint, FWIW.